# node.js SSL encryption without authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, encryption

When a client connects to a node.js SSL server and is not authenticated, i.e.:

- server doesn't require it, i.e. uses `requestCert: false`
- or client certificate is "wrong", i.e. the `secureConnection` event is fired on the SSL server but `Cleartextstream.authorized` is `false`

Is the communication between the client and the server still encrypted (authentication and confidentiality being two different things)?

Another way to put it: does node.js SSL server falls back as a normal/unencrypted TCP server if there are authentication problems, but still fires a `secureConnection` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between the client and the server is always encrypted if you're using SSL server. So if somebody captures your traffic, he won't be able to read it (but you make MitM attack easier).

But why do you asking it here, if you can simply check the traffic using Wireshark?

Comment: Good point for Wireshark. I guess my question was more: does node.js SSL server behaves like a normal TCP server if there are authentication problems?

Comment: it behaves like a normal SSL server... you can check it with `openssl s_client` by the way